# I am missing a closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 136)

Tags: mysql, joomla3.0

I received this error while uploading SQL to server phpMyAdmin. I did look at the answers from similar posts, but I don't think it's the same thing. It should be after -- Table structure for table `wzflh_admintools_log`. These are lines 127 through 146:

```
CREATE TABLE `wzflh_admintools_ipblock` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wzflh_admintools_log`
--

CREATE TABLE `wzflh_admintools_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `logdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` enum('other','adminpw','ipwl','ipbl','sqlishield','antispam','wafblacklist','tpone','tmpl','template','muashield','csrfshield','badbehaviour','geoblocking','rfishield','dfishield','uploadshield','xssshield','httpbl','loginfailure','securitycode','external','awayschedule','admindir','sessionshield','nonewadmins','nonewfrontendadmins','configmonitor','phpshield') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `extradata` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a database named `mydb` and imported your tables via the console. This is what I have:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE `wzflh_admintools_ipblock` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `wzflh_admintools_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `logdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` enum('other', 'adminpw', 'ipwl', 'ipbl', 'sqlishield',
                'antispam', 'wafblacklist', 'tpone', 'tmpl',
                'template', 'muashield', 'csrfshield',
                'badbehaviour', 'geoblocking', 'rfishield',
                'dfishield', 'uploadshield', 'xssshield', 'httpbl',
                'loginfailure', 'securitycode', 'external',
                'awayschedule', 'admindir', 'sessionshield',
                'nonewadmins', 'nonewfrontendadmins', 'configmonitor',
                'phpshield') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `extradata` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: create a blank sql file and copypaste the code, then import the sql file to your database

Comment: Import this with the current DB?  I have no idea what this will do.  My apologizes.  Will this fix the issue? Clarification needed.

Comment: yes it will or on phpmyadmin, select your db then click sql, on the console, paste the code without these lines "SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";"   and click go

Comment: No I get this already exists error: 
'code'
CREATE TABLE `wzflh_admintools_ipblock` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

MySQL said: Documentation
#1050 - Table 'wzflh_admintools_ipblock' already exists 'code'

Comment: what is the database name?

Comment: centeroakland.sql  Should I just replace the new strings into the old sql areas of the file?  Copy and Paste

Comment: run this query on  DROP TABLE `wzflh_admintools_log`, `wzflh_admintools_ipblock`;

Comment: then run the the create tables query in the first answer

Comment: I dropped the original, and added your queries back in and both came back with check marks.

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste this to your SQL file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Oct 19, 2017 at 07:46 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.16-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.24

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `centeroakland`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wzflh_admintools_ipblock`
--

CREATE TABLE `wzflh_admintools_ipblock` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wzflh_admintools_log`
--

CREATE TABLE `wzflh_admintools_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `logdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` enum('other','adminpw','ipwl','ipbl','sqlishield','antispam','wafblacklist','tpone','tmpl','template','muashield','csrfshield','badbehaviour','geoblocking','rfishield','dfishield','uploadshield','xssshield','httpbl','loginfailure','securitycode','external','awayschedule','admindir','sessionshield','nonewadmins','nonewfrontendadmins','configmonitor','phpshield') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `extradata` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Save it then import it.

Comment: No, it didn't work.  I am going to try an different method to acheive this.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Where is the explanation for this answer? Why he needs to do that?